# Correct usage from function prototype in program

Tags: c

I have to use the following C function in one of my programs (using Kiel compiler):

```
Prototype: int fopen (FILE* f, char* filename, char* mode)
Parameters: 
1. f-Pointer to file structure
2. filename-Pointer to a memory location that contains the filename.
3. mode-Pointer to a memory location that contains the file open mode.
Return Value: 1, if file was opened successfully.
0, otherwise.
```

When I tried this I am getting error:

```
FILE * f;
char* filename;
char* mode;
int t;


filename[0]= 'g';

mode[0]='w';


t= fopen( f, filename[0],mode[0]);
```

Error:

```
COPYRIGHT Copyright (C) 2012 - 2013 ARM Ltd and ARM Germany GmbH. All rights reserved.
*** ERROR C141 IN LINE 171 OF F34x_MSD_F931DC_main.c: syntax error near 'FILE'
*** ERROR C202 IN LINE 171 OF F34x_MSD_F931DC_main.c: 'f': undefined identifier
*** ERROR C141 IN LINE 172 OF F34x_MSD_F931DC_main.c: syntax error near 'char'
*** ERROR C202 IN LINE 172 OF F34x_MSD_F931DC_main.c: 'filename': undefined identifier
*** ERROR C141 IN LINE 173 OF F34x_MSD_F931DC_main.c: syntax error near 'char'
*** ERROR C202 IN LINE 173 OF F34x_MSD_F931DC_main.c: 'mode': undefined identifier
*** ERROR C141 IN LINE 174 OF F34x_MSD_F931DC_main.c: syntax error near 'int'
*** ERROR C202 IN LINE 174 OF F34x_MSD_F931DC_main.c: 't': undefined identifier
*** ERROR C202 IN LINE 177 OF F34x_MSD_F931DC_main.c: 'filename': undefined identifier
*** ERROR C202 IN LINE 179 OF F34x_MSD_F931DC_main.c: 'mode': undefined identifier
*** ERROR C202 IN LINE 182 OF F34x_MSD_F931DC_main.c: 't': undefined identifier

C51 COMPILATION COMPLETE.  0 WARNING(S),  11 ERROR(S)
```

Can someone help me in correct usage ?

**Update:**

When I put the variable declarations at the beginning in the main I managed to remove all the errors. But a new error is coming now:

```
COPYRIGHT Copyright (C) 2012 - 2013 ARM Ltd and ARM Germany GmbH. All rights reserved.
*** ERROR C214 IN LINE 184 OF F34x_MSD_F931DC_main.c: illegal pointer conversion
```

I got some hint [here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_c214.htm), but even then unable to understand how to resolve this issue

Comment: You are implementing own fopen function or you are trying to use library function?

Comment: In the same link you provide you have a correct [fopen](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/rlarm/rlarm_fopen.htm) with a sample

Answer (score 2):

```
int fopen (FILE* f, char* filename, char* mode)
```

This means you should pass a pointer-to-char to argument `filename`, but you are passing `filename[0]`, which is a char. The same happens with argument `mode`.

The code below will do:

```
FILE* f;
char* filename="file.txt";   //assuming the file you want to write in is called file.txt and in the same folder with the project
int t;

t= fopen(f, filename, "w");
```

However, I think you should take some time to fully understand some basics about C. You didn't `malloc` any memory for the pointers, which tends to cause some runtime error. And you seem a little messed up with types. It's better to have a solid foundation before dealing with files, or there will be more problem.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of passing the arguments is

```
            t= fopen(f, filename, mode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, `filename` and `mode` are both `char*`s (pointers to char). However, you're giving `fopen` `filename[0]` and `mode[0]`, both of which are `char`s.

```
char* filename;
char* mode;
t= fopen( f, filename[0],mode[0]);
```

The correct way would be to pass the `char*`s:

```
t= fopen(f, filename, mode);
```

This isn't causing your compilation error, but it will cause run-time errors: You aren't allocating memory for your pointers before dereferencing them. You can solve this a few ways:

1: Declaring them as arrays:

```
char filename[2] = "g";
char mode[2] = "w";
...
```

2: Dynamically allocating memory:

```
char * filename = calloc(2,1);
char * mode = calloc(2,1);
filename[0]= 'g';
mode[0]='w';
...
free(filename);
free(mode);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes, that let me think, that you are not experienced with C-pointers. Therefore, beside your question:

a) All pointers are uninitialized. This will lead to undefined behavior.

b) All pointers points to unreserved memory. This will lead to undefined behavior.

c) `filename` and `mode` are `char *` and considered to be strings. They must be 0-terminated.

With a higher relationship to the subject of your question:

d) You do not pass a pointer, but the first element of an array, the pointer should point to (and does *not*).

Probably you want to do something like this:

```
t= fopen( f, "g", "w");
```

This works, because string literals are `char *` in C.

e) There is already an `fopen()` in C.

f) If you have qour own `fopen()` it should porbably return an entity of type `FILE *` via parameter list. There are two ways to do this:

You have an entity of the type `FILE` and pass a pointer to this:

```
 FILE file;
 t= fopen( &file, "g", "w");
```

`fopen()` creates that entity, so you have an entity of type `FILE *` and pass an pointer to this:

```
FILE *file;
t= fopen( &file, "g", "w");
```

I highly recommend to spent further time on learning, how pointers work in C. It is not easy.